# Difficulties to install Ethereum command line

Tags: go-ethereum, installation, command-line

I tried to install command line tools to Ethereum. 
I follow this [tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/cli)

I already do this commands :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

And after I do this : `geth console`

But since for 30 min I have this:

[image]

What is it? I think this downloads something but where?

Moreover I read the tutorial and after this command I must connect to private network. But can I connect to main network? If it's possible how can I do this?

I'm beginner, and I don't have any accounts, so before connect to a network, must I create an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imported 2048 blocks` is normal as it is synchronising the main blockchain with the network. With `geth console`, you are not on a private network but on the main one. Are you on a Mac? You can find the stuff here `~/Library/Ethereum/`. You are at height 102,270, it will go on until at least 2,119,772.

`timed out DAO fork-check` is also normal after the Ethereum hard-fork. It means that it is dropping nodes that are on the other fork. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4tam34/timed_out_dao_forkcheck_dropping/

Comment: Thank for your anwser!!! Yes I'm on a Mac, why? 2,119,772?!?! Is existing an other way, because it will be very long to finish this ...

Comment: The path `~/Library/Ethereum/` is true on Mac. There are other ways to import the blockchain, but you would need to trust the other party. Look up "import".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried common software properties
use below command to install in ubuntu

(1)  install common software properties

(2) sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

update command is required to complete the process

(3) sudo apt-get update

now finally install ethereum

(4) sudo apt-get install ethereum